# Ansible how to check and wait for docker to be up and running in multiple hosts?

Tags: docker, ansible

In my Ansible task I am restarting docker:

```yaml
- name:  restarting docker on all the nodes 
  command: systemctl restart docker
  become: yes
```

After this how can i check and wait till docker is up and running and then proceed to next tasks?

Comment: Use the [`service`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/modules/service_module.html) module rather than a shell command.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but using service module, does it help to wait for docker to be up and running?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using services it's easier actually.
This should work just tried

```
- name: wait for docker service
      service:
        name: docker
        state: started 
      register: docker_service
      until: docker_service.status.ActiveState == "active"
      retries: 10
      delay: 20
```

Comment: Latest version of ansible and docker returns:
{"msg": "The conditional check 'docker_service.status.ActiveState == \"active\"' failed. The error was: error while evaluating conditional (docker_service.status.ActiveState == \"active\"): 'dict object' has no attribute 'status'"}

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
- name: Wait for service 'docker' to be running
  service_facts:
  register: sfax
  until: "sfax.ansible_facts.services.docker.state == 'running'"
  retries: 10
  delay: 5
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/service_facts_module.html
&

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#retrying-a-task-until-a-condition-is-met

Something like that:

```
- name: Wait for service 'docker' to be running
  service_facts:
  until: "(ansible_facts.services | selectattr('name', 'docker')).state == 'running'"
  retries: 10
  delay: 5
```

Comment: I tried using above task, but getting this error: `The conditional check '(ansible_facts.services | selectattr('name', 'docker')).state == 'running''' failed. The error was: template error while templating string: unexpected char u"'" at 80. String: {% if (ansible_facts.services | selectattr('name', 'docker')).state == 'running'' %} True {% else %} False {% endif %}`

Comment: Yes, there was  a typo in the `until:` line. The `''` at the end should just be `'`. I've fixed it.

Comment: I have tried the updated, but it fails with `The conditional check '(ansible_facts.services | selectattr('name', 'docker')).state == 'running'' failed. The error was: error while evaluating conditional ((ansible_facts.services | selectattr('name', 'docker')).state == 'running'): 'generator object' has no attribute 'state'`